# Why are the alignment padding rules different when inheriting from an aggregate?

Tags: c++, c++11

If we have this class:

```
class NotAggregate
{
    double foo;
    int bar;
};
```

The size is 16 bytes because 4 bytes of padding are required to have correct alignment.

If we inherit from this class

```
struct NotAggregateChild : public NotAggregate
{
    int baz;
};
```

The `sizeof(NotAggregateChild)` is still `16`, because the compiler is able to use the padding from the parent for the baz member.

However, if NotAggregate was an Aggregate (i.e. we add public: or change to a struct), the `sizeof` the child changes to `24`.

I'm assuming this has to do with optimisations in copying aggregates (i.e. it's likely just a memcpy on the full type, which would end up overwriting child members). But that is just a guess.

Can anyone tell me what the actual reason for this optimisation being disallowed is?

https://godbolt.org/z/8jMfnnEvW